# converting class less code to class structure

Tags: python, class

I am adding some values in dictionary.
Original code was without class, so I wrote class and tried to run same code. Which gives error.

original code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2da54d3db5b867529fd8

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key in self:
            return self.get(key)
        return 0

pos = MyDict()
neg = MyDict()
```

Where should I define pos, neg if I use class structure?

New code - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b0e84df9a05f165ea2dd

Error is in 4th line of for loop

```
def train(self):
    global pos, neg, totals
    retrain = False

    # Load counts if they already exist.
    if not retrain and os.path.isfile(CDATA_FILE):
        pos, neg, totals = cPickle.load(open(CDATA_FILE))
        return

    limit = 12500
    for file in os.listdir("./aclImdb/train/pos")[:limit]:
        for word in set(self.negate_sequence(open("./aclImdb/train/pos/" + file).read())):
            pos[word] += 1
            neg['not_' + word] += 1
    for file in os.listdir("./aclImdb/train/neg")[:limit]:
        for word in set(self.negate_sequence(open("./aclImdb/train/neg/" + file).read())):
            neg[word] += 1
            pos['not_' + word] += 1
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sentiment_worker.py", line 144, in <module>
    MyDict().gearman_worker.work()
  File "sentiment_worker.py", line 26, in __init__
    self.train()
  File "sentiment_worker.py", line 76, in train
    pos[word] += 1
KeyError: 'all'
```

Comment: This is very unclear. Your "original" code there *is* a class, but it has no relation to the `train` function. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: in __init__ ? or maybe you can use a defaultDict

Comment: @Benjamin: Thanks, defaultDict helped, but dont know what it is

Comment: A dict with a type and a defautl value of this type if the key does not exist yet. Like the 'all' key in your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using dict type for pos in second version which throws error for invalid keys.

```
pos = dict()
```

First version has MyDict which is checking if key exists and returns 0 for invalid keys.

```
pos = MyDict()
```

you can use

```
from collections import defaultdict
pos = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
```